# Batch file is not executing python script (from laravel)

Tags: python-3.x, laravel, pandas

I'm trying to run a batch file in Laravel that's going to execute a python script. The thing is, it was working at the start when the python script had a simple mission: Fetching a file name of a CSV file from the database and then save it in a text file. The resulting file was in the public folder. But then when I changed the python script to do an ACP script, nothing happened when I execute the batch file.

Here are some explanations of what I'm actually trying to do:
The python script fetches the file name from the database, then it starts the ACP process.
The batch file, python script, and the CSV file are in the same directory. Also, keep in mind that both the python & batch scripts work fine when executed normally (not from Laravel).

Batch file code [runscript.bat]

```
@echo off
"python path\python.exe" "script path\pythonScript.py"
PAUSE
```

Python code: [PythonScript.py]

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys
import mysql.connector
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

#Connect to database
db=mysql.connector.connect(host="localhost",user="root",passwd="",db="databaseName")

#get the filename
cur = db.cursor()
cur.execute("select nom_fichier from posts where used = 'on'")
i = cur.fetchall()
k = str(i)
thefilename = k[3:-4]

#read the file
thefile=pd.read_csv(thefilename)

#Label Encoder
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
lb_make = LabelEncoder()
for i in thefile.head(0):
    if (thefile[i].dtypes != 'int64') | (thefile[i].dtypes != 'float64'):
        thefile[i] = lb_make.fit_transform(thefile[i])

for i in thefile.head(0):
    if (thefile[i].dtypes != 'float64'):
        thefile[i] = thefile[i].astype(float)

y_file = pd.DataFrame()
y_file = pd.DataFrame(columns=['target'])

y_file['target'] = thefile['Churn']
thefile = thefile.drop(columns='Churn')

#Fit Data
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
scaler = MinMaxScaler()
scaler.fit(thefile)

scaled_data = scaler.transform(thefile)

#PCA
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
pca = PCA(n_components=2)
pca.fit(scaled_data)
x_pca = pca.transform(scaled_data)

#Save result is csv file
np.savetxt("mydataACP.csv", x_pca, delimiter=",")

cur.close()
db.close()
```

Laravel Controller function that excutes the batch file

```php
    public function LabelEncoder(){
        exec('path\runScript.bat');
    }
```

View script

```php
<a href="{{action('trainingsController@LabelEncoder')}}">ACP</a>
```

So what I'm expecting is a "mydataACP.csv" file in the public directory. However, nothing happens when the batch file is executed.

Comment: How is your batch file not working. If it is why tag it batch.

Comment: The batch file is working, so is the python script. When I tried to do so from Laravel, it doesn't work. I'm sorry if the tag was misleading, it's my first _'desperate'_ ask here.

Comment: Check your documentation for `Exec`. In some languages only exe files can be executed. CMD.exe runs bat files. So you need to call your batch `cmd /c "c:\mybat.bat"` - see `cmd /?`.

Comment: @Noodles Thank you for your response. I changed the ACP function to the following:

        $batchFileToRun = 'path\runScript.bat';
        exec("cmd /c $batchFileToRun");

However, it still not working.

Comment: Change the `/c` to `/k` and read the error message. See `cmd /?`.